# How can I combine three tables(MySQL)?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have three tables.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'd like to get following result from above tables.

[image]

I am working on Laravel project. So if you can, please use Laravel Query Builder.
And I'd like to add sort by weight.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use SQL left join

```
    select p.id, color.value as 'color',weight.value as 'weight' from Products p
left join Values color on (p.id = color.product_id)
    inner join Fields fcolor on (color.field_id = fcolor.id and fcolor.name = "color")
left join Values weight on (p.id = color.product_id)
    inner join Fields fweight on (weight.field_id = fweight.id and fweight.name = "weight")
```

[View The Result In SQL Command Tool](https://paiza.io/projects/e/rnMSEApd130yVlHS7rRl7Q?theme=twilight)

Comment: Thanks, It is working now. And How can I add sort by weight or color in result table? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can sort by *weight.value* or *color.value*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
$fields = DB::table('fields')->pluck('name', 'id')->all();
$query = DB::table('products')->selectRaw('id as product_id, name as product_name');
foreach ($fields as $id => $value) {
    $raw = sprintf(
        '(select `value` from `values` where `values`.product_id = products.id  and `values`.field_id = %s LIMIT 1) as %s',
        $id,
        $value
    );
    $query->selectRaw($raw);
}
$result  = $query->get()->toArray();
dd($result);
```

result like this

[image]

if product filed can has multiple attributes you can use this one with `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
$fields = DB::table('fields')->pluck('name', 'id')->all();
$query = DB::table('products')->selectRaw('id as product_id, name as product_name');
foreach ($fields as $id => $value) {
    $raw = sprintf(
        '(select GROUP_CONCAT(`value`) from `values` where `values`.product_id = products.id  and `values`.field_id = %s ) as %s',
        $id,
        $value
    );
    $query->selectRaw($raw);
}
$result  = $query->get()->toArray();
dd($result);
```

result like

[image]

Comment: Only correct your table names `products -> Products`

Comment: Thanks, But how can I add sort by weight?